# Cordova inappbrowser deviceready never fires

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a cordova project and i need to use the inappbrowser plugin to open a window with a cordova page inside while the "parent" still runs.

Cordova loads `index.html` which opens `frame.html` using the inappbrowser plugin.
Cordova get's loaded into `frame.html` but the deviceready event never fires and after 5 seconds i get this error in the console of `frame.html`.

***This only happens inside the second webview that is opened using the inappbrowser plugin.***

### Error :

```
cordova.js:1183 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1176 Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady
cordova.js:1176 Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady
```

I searched a lot and i concluded that it is not an excess of plugins or code in the document's onload that delays the onNativeReady event that is required to fire deviceready.
When i remove `cordova-plugin-file` and `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` the `onFileSystemPathsReady` error disappears.
If i remove `cordova-plugin-device` the `onCordovaInfoReady` error disappears.

But i need those plugins.
**What is causing the deviceready event to not fire at all?

And what can i do to get it to fire without removing the plugins i need?**

### Project info :

```
Node version: v4.2.2
Cordova version: 5.4.1

Installed platforms:
    android 4.1.1
    ios 3.9.2

Installed plugins:
    cordova-plugin-bluetoothle 2.4.0 "Bluetooth LE"
    cordova-plugin-device 1.1.0 "Device"
    cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.0 "Notification"
    cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"
    cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.4.0 "File Transfer"
    cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.1.0 "InAppBrowser"
    cordova-plugin-vibration 2.0.0 "Vibration"
    cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.0 "Whitelist"
    de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode 0.6.4 "BackgroundMode"  

Config.xml file:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.test.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
    <name>TestApp</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

#### index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head >
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';" >
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" >
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" >
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, height=device-height, width=device-width" >
        <title >Index</title >
        <script >
            document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', function ()
            {
                console.log( 'ready' );
                win = window.open( 'frame.html', '_blank', 'location=no', function()
                {
                    console.log( arguments );
                } );
            }, false );
        </script >
    </head >
    <body >
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js" ></script >
    </body >
</html >
```

#### frame.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head >
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';" >
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" >
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" >
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, height=device-height, width=device-width" >
        <title >Frame</title >
        <script >
            window.addEventListener( 'deviceready', function()
            {
                console.log( 'window.deviceready', arguments );
            }, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', function()
            {
                console.log( 'document.deviceready', arguments );
            }, false );
        </script >
    </head >
    <body >
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js" ></script >
    </body >
</html >
```

**Update :**

I am using two self-modified plugins (not the ones that cause the problem), maybe that this is somehow related:

- [BluetoothLE](https://github.com/cvuser0/BluetoothLE/tree/custom)
- [BackgroundMode](https://github.com/cvuser0/cordova-plugin-background-mode)

### Edit :

I need to use the inappbrowser plugin because the bluetoothle plugin has to keep the connection while navigating through the app in the other frame.
The frames also need to be able to communicate with eachother and both have access to cordova libraries.

If someone has other ideas how to do this, i'm open for them.

#### Update :

I'm looking into cl.kunder.webviewhttps://github.com/kunder-lab/cl.kunder.webview plugin

Comment: "deviceready" will call only once when your index.html load first time. if you want to load event with your InAppBrowser i guess you need to use  InAppBrowser events like "loadstart,loadstop,loaderror,exit". 

Not sure this is the solution you looking for but as far as my understanding this is what you want.

Comment: @JDev cordova logs that 2 channels haven't fired. If i remove the plugins that use those 2 channels the deviceready **will** fire. I want it to fire with the plugins installed. those 2 plugins have not finished loading, otherwise the deviceready would fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ThisNameBetterBeAvailable,

No Cordova services are available to the [InAppBrowser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser).

From the documentation (paragraph #3) **I Quote**

> The InAppBrowser window behaves like a standard web browser, **and can't access Cordova APIs.**

This means none of the plugins, none of the event, and none of the services. I've tried to get them to fix this part of the documentation, but it will be a while.

You can see it here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9470

Comment: And i presume that it would be too hard to add those cordova API's myself?
Or is forking it and adding the cordova API's possible?

Comment: A [plugin](https://github.com/cvuser0/cl.kunder.webview) i had used before seems to be able to access the cordova API, only i can't have any communication between the created webview and the webview that initiated it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on the plugin. As of this moment, there are 13 [webview alternatives](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=webview) in the Cordova Plugin Repsository; many are clones of one or two base sources. I try to keep a running blog of "official" [webview](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/webview.md) libraries, their [details](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/webview-details.md) and [alternatives](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/webview-alternatives.md).

Comment: A common alternative to Cordova Plugins is the HTML5 APIs. Depending on the platform, you have access to GPS(geolocation), camera, localstorage, and others. On your question, If your goal is simply bluetooth, you should reconsider your design and possibly use a SPA (single page App) or something similar. Adding is difficult considering the alternatives. You can always fork, and use it as a private plugin. However, the plugin you pointed to goes against all the current "security" changes; it won't be allowed by Google, Apple or Phonegap.

Comment: Fetching a webpage from a website is considered dangerous - and a line is created between that and the app. To work with Cordova/Phonegap you'll need to add the *whitelist*. This *whitelist* worksheet should help. [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md) Best of Luck

Comment: i know about the security risks, that's why the website address is `http://localhost:8888`. I also figured out the whitelist and that is not the cause because i (for now) allow `*`